# Interfacing Python 3 to NASM via ctypes byref

Tags: python, linux, nasm, x86-64, ctypes

I am using Python 3 with Linux Mint 18 and NASM, and want to write assembly code that uses the x87 FPU registers directly. I should point out that I'm a hardware engineer who also programs, not a programmer. While I am fairly good with python and most assemblers, I have little C, and am not very good around the interfaces.

After a search, I found a recipe on ActiveState (below) which has got me started with getting NASM code into memory and passing ints and floats by value.

As I want to use the FPU, and as that can only be loaded from RAM, the next thing I want to do is pass in a floating value in memory, pointed at by the input register rdi, which I understand is a byref(), the plan being to load the FPU from [rdi].

I have got the simple 'hello world' add integer and move double functions working, down in the if name == 'main' part of the code below. The last function is my Nth attempt at trying to understand (and failing) the syntax for passing a double byref through ctyes to the assembler. I am still a lot of learning away from being able to understand the syntax error messages, and the ctypes examples for not-quite-this-type of situations.

Could someone help me with a correctly working example please.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# python 2 example
# downloaded from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/579037-how-to-execute-x86-64-bit-assembly-code-directly-f/

# change to python 3 only required string.encode to get bytes, and print()

import subprocess, os, tempfile
from ctypes import *

PAGE_SIZE = 4096    

class AssemblerFunction(object):

  def __init__(self, code, ret_type, *arg_types):

    # get handle and file names for temp files
    (fd, source_name) = tempfile.mkstemp(".S", "assembly", os.getcwd())
    object_name = os.path.splitext(source_name)[0]

    # write code string out to source file
    os.write(fd, code.encode('utf-8'))  ## convert code string to code bytes
    os.close(fd)

    # run NASM on the source
    subprocess.check_call(["nasm",source_name])
    # it creates an object file without the extension

    # get the ojbect code
    with open(object_name, 'rb') as fbin:
        binary = fbin.read()     
    bin_len = len(binary)

    # clean up temporary files     
    os.unlink(source_name)
    os.unlink(object_name)

    # align our code on page boundary.
    self.code_buffer = create_string_buffer(PAGE_SIZE*2+bin_len)
    addr = (addressof(self.code_buffer) + PAGE_SIZE) & (~(PAGE_SIZE-1))
    memmove(addr, binary, bin_len)    

    # Change memory protection
    self.mprotect = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6").mprotect
    mp_ret = self.mprotect(addr, bin_len, 4)   # execute only. 
    if mp_ret: raise OSError("Unable to change memory protection")

    self.func = CFUNCTYPE(ret_type, *arg_types)(addr)
    self.addr = addr
    self.bin_len = bin_len

  def __call__(self, *args):
    return self.func(*args)

  def __del__(self):
    # Revert memory protection
    if hasattr(self,"mprotect"):
      self.mprotect(self.addr, self.bin_len, 3)   


if __name__ == "__main__":

  # input parameters go in via the following registers
  # 1, RDI; 2, RSI; 3, RDX; 4, RCX; 5, R8; 6, R9

  # add integer example, WORKS  
  add_func_2i = """ BITS 64
                    mov rax, rdi    ; Move the first parameter
                    add rax, rsi    ; add the second parameter
                    ret             ; rax will be returned
                    """

  Add_int_2 = AssemblerFunction(add_func_2i, c_int, c_int, c_int)
  print(Add_int_2(1, 2))
  print(Add_int_2(4, 5))

  # move a floating value from input to rax, WORKS
  move_dub = """ BITS 64
                    mov rax, rdi    ; Move the first parameter
                    ret             ; rax will be returned 
                    """

  echo_dub = AssemblerFunction(move_dub, c_double, c_double)
  print(echo_dub(4.321))

# move a floating value from input* to rax, no joy yet
  move_deref_dub = """ BITS 64
                    mov rax, [rdi]    ; Move the first parameter
                    ret               ; rax will be returned 
                    """

  dub_in = c_double(1.0)

  echo_ddub = AssemblerFunction(move_deref_dub, c_double, byref(dub_in))
  print(echo_ddub(54.321))
```

Comment: In 64-bit code on Linux floating point values will get passed in the vector registers XMM0 to XMM7. and will return floating point values in XMM0/XMM1 (not RAX) You should review the 64-bit Linux System V ABI. You can review the ABI here: https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI  (rev 252 is the latest 64-bit one)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I was trying to walk before I could run, using the lowest level x86/x87 compatible stuff. I'm using an i5. My second example works, using rdi and rax as the in/out registers, and seems to work. Does your comment mean that values go in on rdi *and* xmm0, or what? Once I can get something in and out, in the right syntax, then I can play with all the other whizzy stuff to my heart's content.

Comment: First off although the x87 instructions are available in 64-bit mode the C calling convention doesn't use them (32-bit Linux though used the x87 FPU). In 64-bit Linux code the SIMD vector registers are used instead. Although you can move values to and from SIMD registers and the x87 FPU stack (in your functions) in most cases it is unwanted overhead.In 64-bit code it is usually preferable to stick with SIMD registers and SIMD instructions.

Comment: To pass a double by pointer then you'd need to use something like `echo_ddub = AssemblerFunction(move_deref_dub, c_double, POINTER(c_double))` and then `print(echo_ddub(c_double(54.321)))`

Comment: In the test code for the floating point test you could try `movsd xmm0, [rdi]` which gets the 64-bit double float at `[rdi]` and moves it into the XMM0 register. As an experiment `addsd xmm0, xmm0` would then double the value in XMM0. XMM0 also happens to be the vector register used to return floats and doubles. So then you just do the `ret`. The end result is that it should print `108.642`

Comment: @Neil_UK, the `mov rax, rdi` example does not work, actually. The value is passed in `xmm0` and returned without change in `xmm0`. It does not get passed in `rdi` and returned in `rax`. Set a breakpoint on the address from `cast(echo_dub.func, c_void_p).value` and print `$xmm0` and `$rdi` to see for yourself.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, your revised prototype, call, and assembly code work. Except I prefer an explicit `echo_ddub(byref(c_double(54.321)))`. I've never liked how ctypes implicitly creates a pointer when passed an instance of the referenced type for a pointer-type argument.

Comment: @eryksun : His Python code (and inline comment) suggested he was trying to pass a pointer to a double. In that case the pointer is in _RDI_

Comment: @MichaelPetch, I meant that I prefer explicitly passing `byref(c_double(54.321))`. When you pass `c_double(54.321)` without `byref`, you're relying on ctypes to create the pointer for you *implicitly*, which it will happily do, but it makes reading the code ambiguous as to what gets passed without having to search the source for the prototype definition.

Comment: Am I complicating things by using activeState's 'build a general function' function? Would it be simpler to build a specific function? In fact, my eventual function signature will be int func(*double_array), which could be simpler, and trying to pass and return doubles as a baby step on the way to that is adding extra trouble?